# Is there a way to compress a Silverlight Pivot Collection's cxml file?

Tags: silverlight, pivotviewer, cxml-collectionxml

I generated a large (31K items) pivot collection whose cxml file exceeds 21 megs. I would need to host this on a website however 21 megs is going to take a long time for the client silverlight pivot viewer control to load. I intend to use gzip compression to serve the file however is there anything better that can be done?

Is there a way to compress a Silverlight Pivot Collection's cxml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using compression on the web server is your only real bet.

However, 31k is not going to work very well.  Typically, if you break the 3k mark you start seeing bad performance, slow load times, etc.

I would look at your data and see if there is a way to break it up.  Either linking collections, creating hierarchies, etc.  That would get your users a better experience.

Sorry there isn't a better answer for you.

Comment: Can't break it up; can't think of a better way either. :(

Comment: I really don't think you are going to get it to successfully work at that size.  That is a ton of data to push across the pipe and I doubt the PivotViewer will handle the volume of items.

Comment: Ok, I will have to invent something. Pivot is too cool to be left as a "toy" application.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using SL5 version, but if so, I've found that the client [doesn't allow](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightbugs/thread/36896549-243c-49a6-9d18-b3ad54c95490/) the server to send a compressed version of the CXML file.  However, Tony is right in saying that 31K items is WAY to many for PivotViewer to deal with.  Consider implementing a "gate" that allows you to generate a subset of those items (simulate a user already selecting values one of the facets)